# Sort list of objects by varying parameter

Tags: c#, linq

In my project I have this class:

```
public class AccountData
{
    private const string DATE_FORMAT = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm";

    private string userName;
    private long creationDate, lastModificationDate;

    public ProjectData()
    {
        this.userName = Environment.UserName;
        creationDate = lastModificationDate = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
    }

    public void UpdateLastModified()
    {
        lastModificationDate = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
    }

    #region Properties
    public string CreationDate => new DateTime(creationDate).ToString(DATE_FORMAT);
    public string LastModificationDate => new DateTime(lastModificationDate).ToString(DATE_FORMAT);
    public string UserName => userName;
    #endregion
}
```

And I need to display a list of this class (`System.Generic.List<AccountData>()`).

I am able to display it correctly, but I also want to add an option to sort the data by one of the parameters. i.e. If the user selected sort by creationDate, all the items in the list would be sourted by this value.

But I am unable to find a solution that would be flexible.

This is what I have got so far:

```
private void SortItemsBy(string by)
{
    List<AccountData> accounts = GetAccounts();
    switch (by)
    {
        case "Last Modified":
            Sort(accounts, data => data.LastModificationDate);
            break;
        case "Creation Date":
            Sort(accounts, data => data.CreationDate);
            break;
        case "User Name":
            Sort(accounts, data => data.UserName);
            break;
    }
}

private void Sort(IEnumerable<AccountData> accounts, Func<AccountData, string> predicate)
{
    var orderedAccounts = accounts.OrderBy(predicate);
    DisplayAccounts(orderedAccounts);
}
```

As you can see I am basing the sort on a string value which (as far as I know) is prone to errors.

Is there a better way to do it¿

Comment: Are you just wanting to be able to sort with having to convert everything to string? Or is it something more than that?

Comment: Is there any reason you're representing `DateTime` fields with a `string`? That's incredibly limiting - `string` is used for display, but any other use of those properties will have to convert them back to `DateTime` again.

Comment: @RufusL No, the property is just for displaying it. The sort would be by the DateTime class

Comment: @RossGurbutt No, it was just for testing to see that the code works. I would use the read type of the objects (e.g. creation data as DateTime)

Comment: Have you considered making the return type of the predicate generic, and then use the `DateTime` class to parse the string properties that are actually dates into `DateTime` objects? Then the sorting should work as expected.

Comment: You should create an enum for sort column. And have 3 values in that enum. And use that enum in the method instead of string parameter.

Comment: @RufusL The sorting works OK, but I want to be able to sort by other properties (according to the user selection). So the sort might be according to the user name, or any other property I would add to the `AccountData` class

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya This would improve the code a bit. I would try it

Comment: If the sorting works ok, then what is the question? I thought there was an issue with sorting by the `DateTime` property.

Comment: @RufusL The question is how to change the sorting category dynamically, so the user would be able to select how to sort the data

Comment: Ok. But that sorting by `DateTime` is not going to work, since the `day` is presented first, it will order all the dates by `day` first, then by `month`, then by `year`, when typically it's done the other way around (anything from the year 2000 should be "less than" anything from the year 2020).

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understood intend of your question. You could modify the Sort Method to include the Original DataType of the Property that needs to be sorted.You could then use [`Convert.ChangeType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.changetype?view=netcore-3.1) to convert the string property to intended Type.  For example,

```
private void Sort<TDataType>(IEnumerable<AccountData> accounts, Func<AccountData, string> predicate)
{
    var orderedAccounts = accounts.OrderBy(x=> (TDataType)Convert.ChangeType(predicate.Invoke(x),typeof(TDataType),new CultureInfo("en-IN"))); 
    DisplayAccounts(orderedAccounts);
}
```

Now you could sort using

```
Sort<string>(list,x=>x.Name);
Sort<DateTime>(list,x=>x.CreationDate);
Sort<DateTime>(list,x=>x.LastModificationDate);
```

[Demo Code](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jXhqpC)